# How to connect 2 tuples together not merging with python

Tags: python

Suppose I have

```
a = [(1,2)]
b = [(3,4)]
```

I want C as a connect from a and b tuple but not merging them together

```
 C = [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

I tried with add but they are merged together.

Comment: `[(1, 2)]` is a list of tuples, not a tuple. Did you mean just `a = (1, 2)`?

Comment: Isn't this question a ["use jQuery"](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)-like kind of trolling?

Answer (score 3):

in your example you have two lists of tuples, you can just do :

```
a = [(1,2)]
b = [(3,4)]
C = a + b

>>>C
[(1,2),(3,4)]
```

The `;` is not needed, Python does not require semi-colons to terminate statements.